# Fail to run tests in Chrome headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run tests in Chrome headless mode but getting **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Chrome version: Version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
Selenium version: 3.8.1 
Chromedriver version: 2.45.615355

Here is my BaseTest:

```
public abstract class BaseTest {

public WebDriver driver;

protected abstract String getUrl();

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Log.startLog("Test is Starting...");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src//test//resources//chromedriver");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(getUrl());
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    Log.endLog("Test is Ending...");
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.close();
}
}
```

When I'm running tests, not in headless mode every test works good but in headless mode, I can't even run a simple test to understand if the headless mode is working or not.

Test example:
    `@Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }`

Example URL: https://www.wikipedia.org/

*UPDATE:*
I've created new sample project with this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/alexsomov/Desktop/chromedriver2");

    //Set Chrome Headless mode as TRUE
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setHeadless(true);

    //Instantiate Web Driver
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    System.out.println("Page title is - " + driver.getTitle());

    driver.close();
}
```

And bingo, everything works well... Need to figure out why code above from real project doesn't work seems something wrong with BaseTest class and when I run code with debugger I'm getting *driver == null*, maybe anyone have a solution how I can solve this problem :/

*ANSWER*
The solution was super easy, just need to change 1 string in setUp() method in BaseTest class.

This one:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

change to this:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux environment, may be you have to add --no-sandbox as well and also specific window size settings. --no-sandbox is no needed in windows if you set user container properly.

disable-gpu Only on Windows. Other platforms no longer require it. The --disable-gpu flag is a temporary work around for a few bugs.

```
if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("HLChrome")){
            //Headless chrome browser and configure
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-gpu");
//            chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1400,2100"); // linux should be activate
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you! But I've tried with             
     chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
Also tried with window size and it didn't help :( The same NullpointerException appear.

Comment: So are you using Linux environment ? Its better if you can use chrome driver manager. it will reduce your space and easy to implement  with CI tools as well.
But can you post your tested code with --headless here. ? because I'm not sure whether you fix it correctly.

Comment: I'm using MacOs high sierra, added update to the post, seems something with driver initialisation for test, because in sample project (code above) everything works well, I think I need somehow change BaseTest class... but don't know how

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER The solution was super easy, just need to change 1 string in setUp() method in BaseTest class.

This one:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

change to this:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

and everything will work.